# How to add Auth Custom claims

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

## Firebase function

I am trying to set my user role to admin using a callable function:

```js
export const addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(data.uid, {
    admin: true,
    seller: false,
  });
});
```

## Cient

And here is how I am calling the function on the client:

```
 const register = (email: string, password: string) => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        const addAdminRole = httpsCallable(functions, "addAdminRole");
        addAdminRole({ email: user.email, uid: user.uid })
          .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        history.push(`/home/${user.uid}`);
      })

      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // ..
      });
  };
```

The user is created but, my Admin role is not added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may come from the fact that you don't correctly handle the promise returned by the `setCustomUserClaims()` method in your Cloud Function and therefore the Cloud Function platform may clean up you CF before it reaches its terminating state. Correctly managing the life-cycle of your Cloud Function is key, as explained [here in the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

The following should solve the problem:

```
export const addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(data.uid, {
            admin: true,
            seller: false,
          });
          
          return {result: "Success"}
    } catch (error) {
        // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
    }
  });
```

---

In addition, you can refactor your front-end code as follows to correctly [chain the promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining):

```
const register = (email: string, password: string) => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        const addAdminRole = httpsCallable(functions, "addAdminRole");
        return addAdminRole({ email: user.email, uid: user.uid });        
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        history.push(`/home/${user.uid}`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // ..
      });
  };
```